Acceleration equation $a=-∇Φ(x)$
In Jolien D.E. Creighton's and Warren G.Anderson's book “Gravitational-Wave Physics and Astronomy” it states that $a=-∇Φ(x)$. What is the value of ∇?  It states that ∇ is the gradient operator in x, but what does that mean?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

You can read more about the $\nabla$  operator
in Wikipedia - Gradient (especially the subsection "Cartesian coordinates").
The vector equation
$$\mathbf{a}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\Phi(\mathbf{x})$$
is short-hand notation for the three equations in Cartesian components
$$\begin{align}
a_x=-\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial x} \\
a_y=-\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial y} \\
a_z=-\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial z}
\end{align}$$
